# `block in non_options': file not found: (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I'm trying to open browser url based on argument passed to script. Hence I wrote following ruby code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class TestTitle < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    if ARGV[0] == 'google'
      $driver.get 'http://www.google.com'
    elsif ARGV[0] == 'twitter'
      $driver.get 'http://www.twitter.com'
    end
  end

  def test_title
    puts $driver.title
  end

  def teardown
    $driver.quit
  end
end
```

When I passed argument: `ruby test.rb 'google'`, it results into following error:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: google (ArgumentError)
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How did you run from the command prompt your .rb file?

Comment: `ruby test.rb 'google'`

Comment: The second parameter of your shell command is interpreted as a file not an ARGV argument. Testunit does not even touches your code so far. What version of testunit are you running? Is `ruby` an alias?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you mean(in my case) `$ruby test.rb 'google'`. `test.rb` is ARGV[0] and `google` is ARGV[1]. But when I try ARGV[1] instead of ARGV[0] in my code, I observe same error. testunit version, I'm running is 2.5.5

Answer (score 3):

It appears that test-unit (as of 1.9.1) grabs command line options in its GlobOptions module. You are using ARGV[0] to pass browser name, but it thinks you're passing a file name. A workaround is to capture the value of ARGV[0] and then clear it before your test case runs:

> `browser = ARGV[0]`
>
> `ARGV[0] = nil`